# Make a Git push with PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, git, symfony, push

With my Symfony project, I would like commit and push immediatly an image that i upload. For the moment, only the push doesn't work. For the others commands, I do this :

```
exec('git add myfile');
exec('git -c user.name="My User Name" -c user.email="my email" commit -m "My Commit"');
```

For the push, i try do this :

```
$branch = exec("git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2");
exec('git push https_link '.$branch);
```

I have no error, no output, juste my script is pending a long time and i need to restart Apache.
It's a simple authentification (I use bitbucket with my dedicated URL on https) then I don't need password. I try with proc_open too but it's the same.
I see the library https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php but I don't arrive to install it with Symfony

Comment: Side-question: Why do you store binary files in git?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find what the error message is. If you are using Symfony you should use [Process Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). Most likely will be problem with authentication to bitbucket. Don't forget PHP usually runs under different user than you are using, so all SSH config / ENV variables are different.

With it it will be something like

```
$process = new Process(array('ls', '-lsa'));
$process->run('git -c user.name="My User Name" -c user.email="my email" commit -m "My Commit"');
$output = $process->getOutput(); // here you should see the output - Time to find where is problem
```